# Different integrals for volume of solid

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by $ y = x^2, x = y^2 $ around the line $ y = 1 $.

Here is my attempt. The region of interest is bounded by the curves $ y = x^2, y = \sqrt{x} $. These two curves intercept at $ x = 0, 1 $. The solid has a cross-section of a washer with outer radius $ 1 − x^2 $ and inner radius $ 1 - \sqrt{x} $, so its volume is

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \pi(1 - x^2)^2 - \pi(1 - \sqrt{x})^2dx = \frac{11 \pi}{30}. $$

This is the correct answer, but now I'm trying to see if I can set up the integral with respect to $ y $. The outer radius is now $ 1 - \sqrt{y} $ and the inner radius is now $ 1 - y^2 $. So the integral is
$$ \int_{0}^{2} \pi(1 - \sqrt{y})^2 - \pi(1 - y^2)^2dy, $$
which does not give me the same answer. Where did I make the mistake? What should be the correct integral with respect to $ y $?

Comment: One uses disks, the other shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtaining that volume integrating with respect to $y$ means computing that volume using the shell method. But, since you are computing the volume of a region rotated around the line $y=1$, this means to compute$$\int_0^12\pi(1-y)\left(\sqrt y-y^2\right)\,\mathrm dy,$$which is equal to $\frac{11\pi}{30}$, as it should be.

Comment: José, since the length of the segment in which the line $Y=y$ intersects the region bounded by $X=Y^2$ and $X=\sqrt Y$, is $\sqrt y-y^2$, I think it would be better to write that the volume of the region rotated around the line $Y=1$ is $$\int_0^12\pi(1-y)\left(\sqrt y-y^2\right)\mathrm dy\,.$$ I know that it is equal to the integral you wrote, but I think that when we use the shell method, we have to write the length of the section of the region with the line $Y=y$ which is $\sqrt y-y^2.\,$ Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Angelo Yes, I agree. Done.